# Editing xml using bash and awk, awk don't replace text

Tags: xml, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a config file, with new version code, like a SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011, and this number is write to config.txt, and this number I must place in 4 places on this xml file.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NewNumber=`cat config.txt`

echo $NewNumber
#This number is: PLE31Z_BNE_1111_1121211_313131

awk '/"Parameter1"/ && !done++{sub(/Parameter1="[A-Z0-9]"/, "Parameter1=\"'$NewNumber'\"")}1' OldFileWithVersionNumeber.xml > temp.xml && mv -f temp.xml Newfile$NewNumber.xml

#I know, I must write 3 awk, but first one doesn't work for now

cat targettext.xml | grep Parameter1
```

XML with old parameter:

```
<OneSection Parameter1="SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011" Parameter2="SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011" Type="UWE-AD" date="05/01/2011">

 AND LOT OF VERY SIMILAR LINES
 AND TWO LINES WITH THE SAME NUMBER TO REPLACE

<xmlElement Name="" name="NameGB" version="_SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011.xml" Unit="ERF" Blocks="1" params1="" params2="" Path1="/rom/" path2="" comp="" encrypted="">
<xmlElement KeyName="" name="NameGB" version="_SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011.xml" Unit="ERFS" Blocks="1" params1="" params2="" Path1="/rom/" path2="" comp="" encrypted="">
```

Comment: It looks to me like the purpose of `!done++` was to restrict the match to the first line.  Is that correct?

Comment: Its better to avoid using old and outdated back tics, use parentheses: `NewNumber=$(cat config.txt)`.  Also do not use `cat` with program that can read data itself: `grep Parameter1 targettext.xml`

Comment: Do not use variable inside `awk` expression.  Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as the `awk` command:

```
$ awk -v new="$NewNumber" '/Parameter1/ && NR==1{sub(/Parameter1="[[:alnum:]_]*/, "Parameter1=\""new)} 1' OldFileWithVersionNumeber.xml
<OneSection Parameter1="PLE31Z_BNE_1111_1121211_313131" Parameter2="SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011" Type="UWE-AD" date="05/01/2011">

 AND LOT OF VERY SIMILAR LINES
 AND TWO LINES WITH THE SAME NUMBER TO REPLACE

<xmlElement Name="" name="NameGB" version="_SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011.xml" Unit="ERF" Blocks="1" params1="" params2="" Path1="/rom/" path2="" comp="" encrypted="">
<xmlElement KeyName="" name="NameGB" version="_SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011.xml" Unit="ERFS" Blocks="1" params1="" params2="" Path1="/rom/" path2="" comp="" encrypted="">
```

#### How it works

- `-v new="$NewNumber"`

  This defines an `awk` variable called `new` that contains the value of `NewNumber`.
- `/Parameter1/ && NR==1`

  This selects lines that (1) contain `Parameter1` and (2) are the first line of the file (`NR==1`).
- `sub(/Parameter1="[[:alnum:]_]*/, "Parameter1=\""new)`

  This does the substitution.  Note three changes to the regex:

  - By using `[:alnum:]` in place of `[A-Z0-9]`, the regex is now safe for Unicode fonts.
  - The underline character was added to the allowed characters.
  - A `*` is added after `[[:alnum:]_]` so that zero or more characters can be matched.  Previously, it matched only one.

  Note also that the substitution text now uses the variable `new`.  This avoids shell-quoting issues and also is safer if `NewNumber` were to contain `awk`-active characters.

#### Changing both `parameter1` and `parameter2`

The following code changes both `parameter1` and `parameter2` if they occur on the second line of the input file:

```
$ awk --posix -v new="$NewNumber" '/Parameter1/ && NR==2{sub(/Parameter1="[[:alnum:]_]*/, "Parameter1=\""new); sub(/Parameter2="[[:alnum:]_]*/, "Parameter2=\""new)} 1' OldFileWithVersionNumeber.xml

<OneSection Parameter1="PLE31Z_BNE_1111_1121211_313131" Parameter2="PLE31Z_BNE_1111_1121211_313131" Type="UWE-AD" date="05/01/2011">

 AND LOT OF VERY SIMILAR LINES
 AND TWO LINES WITH THE SAME NUMBER TO REPLACE

<xmlElement Name="" name="NameGB" version="_SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011.xml" Unit="ERF" Blocks="1" params1="" params2="" Path1="/rom/" path2="" comp="" encrypted="">
<xmlElement KeyName="" name="NameGB" version="_SAD10A_BNA_1234_123456_110011.xml" Unit="ERFS" Blocks="1" params1="" params2="" Path1="/rom/" path2="" comp="" encrypted="">
```

Comment: Thanks for You fast response.
unfortunately You awk doesn't work :(
i put You awk to my script

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  If you run it by itself, as shown in answer, do you get the same result that I show?  Is that the result that you want?  Alternatively, if the problem only happens when the `awk` line is part of the script, what exactly are the symptoms?

Comment: If i add this line to script, this awk doesn't replace parameter1,
parameter1 is the same, parameter2 too.

Comment: I Found error, You put in awk NR==1, but it is my second line:) and change number to 2, and now it works :)
How I can change parameter2 in this xml ?

Comment: @Dzions  Very good.  I added a new version that changes both parameters if they occur on the second line of the file.